# Android Studio SqlLite sync with Firebase

Tags: android, sqlite, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am programming a Chat Application. I save the data for my Chats in a Firebase Database. I now want to sync Firebase with a SqlLite Database, so the data is also offline available. I  know that Firebase has Offline Capabilities, but as I know it can only store Strings. But I want to save up to 8 Strings per Chat. And I think that a SqlLite is the best way to achieve it.

If this is even possible...
Maybe someone had the same problem and created a class to do so.

Comment: How is a MySQL database available offline?  Do you mean SQLite, which is embedded in Android?

Comment: Oh sorry. I mean SqlLite

Comment: Should be possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I had a SqlLite Database. And every time I load my Chats I deleted everthing from the database and rewrote it with the new data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data will be available also offline even if you don't use SQLite. Using this line of code:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

Means that Firebase will maintains it's own internal (local) version of the database (based on SQLite) that will help you query your the database even if you don't have internet connection. So, every change that is made while you are offline, will be added in a queue and will be updated on Firebase servers once you are back online.

It is **not true** that Firebase does store only String values. It can store:

- String
- Long
- Double
- Boolean
- Map
- List

And also there is no limitation for the number of strings that you want to store.

Comment: When I am loading a List via a ValueEventListener and  then put the list into a RecyclerAdapter. Does this still work?

Comment: Yes, definitely.

Comment: where do I have to call this method? In my MainActivity?

Comment: because I am getting an error when i go back to it saying: Calls to setPersistenceEnabled() must be made before any other usage of FirebaseDatabase instance.